# Javascript Prototypes - Can't we just add into the object instead?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Using Codeacadamy to gain an understanding with JavaScript. I have reached a point where prototypes are having a big impact in all I code. 
I understand that in simple terms, prototypes are a way of adding methods or properties to a class. Is it not just more convenient to find the original class and just pop the property / method into it instead before you lose track of whats where?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are no real classes in javascript as you can have them in Java or C++. All you have are some sort of **fake classes**.

There are several ways to give javascript variables an object behaviour, and `prototype` is one of them. The other two are **using object literals** (as if you were writing a json object) and **using a singleton function**.

You can see a very good explanation here: http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/